NullPointerException in Dataflow: import from MongoDB
I'm trying to create dataflow job importing data from MongoDB to BigQuery. Unfortunately there is a NullPointerException thrown and I don't know why.
I use flex template.
Error message:
      Root cause: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.mongodb.templates.MongoDbToBigQuery$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:803)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:348)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:275)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1792)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$3000(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:143)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$NonWindowObservingProcessBundleContext.output(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2650)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.transforms.JavascriptDocumentTransformer$TransformDocumentViaJavascript$1.processElement(JavascriptDocumentTransformer.java:239)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.transforms.JavascriptDocumentTransformer$TransformDocumentViaJavascript$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:803)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:348)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:275)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1792)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$3000(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:143)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$WindowObservingProcessBundleContext.outputWithTimestamp(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2219)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.Read$BoundedSourceAsSDFWrapperFn.processElement(Read.java:322)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.Read$BoundedSourceAsSDFWrapperFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForWindowObservingSizedElementAndRestriction(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1100)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$1500(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:143)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:659)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:654)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:348)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:275)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.BeamFnDataReadRunner.forwardElementToConsumer(BeamFnDataReadRunner.java:213)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataInboundObserver.multiplexElements(BeamFnDataInboundObserver.java:158)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:537)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:150)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:115)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UnboundedScheduledExecutorService$ScheduledFutureTask.run(UnboundedScheduledExecutorService.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.mongodb.templates.MongoDbUtils.getTableSchema(MongoDbUtils.java:148)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.mongodb.templates.MongoDbToBigQuery$1.process(MongoDbToBigQuery.java:146)

I'm using Python's DataflowStartFlexTemplateOperator to define a dataflow job. It works for other collections in the same database.
